# My iTunes account shows an incorrect device

Tags: itunes

How do I change my device in iTunes. It shows an inactive iPod but I need it to show my iPhone. I could not locate the area within iTunes that this change should be made.

Comment: Is the issue that the wrong device is showing in the store (authorized devices allowed to play your music) or the wrong device shows inside of iTunes itself for managing the device? EG syncing, backup, music management, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Launch iTunes on your Mac.

Click on your name in the upper right hand corner of iTunes. In the menu, click on **Account Info**.

Type in your iTunes password when prompted in order to continue.

When your account loads, click on Manage Devices under the iTunes in the Cloud section.

[image: itunes]

Click on Remove next to the devices you want to remove.